# How can I bring other applications' windows to the front in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-office

I am using several applications to do my analysis step by step.

Instead of going to other applications (e.g. Excel, Word, IE, SAP, Outlook) by using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> manually, I want a button that will activate the next application and bring it to foreground and focus on it.

And there will be a non-modal dialog box which is coded in Excel VBA and should float around that application like the Search Dialog box in Microsoft Office.

All this functionality should be achieved in Excel VBA 2007.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Answer (score 1):

Later versions of Windows (starting with 2000) are somewhat stricter in activating other applications and forcing them to the front. See the Remarks section on the documentation of [SetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633539%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But since you want to simulate Alt+Tab, I think your best changes are to simulate an Alt+Tab key stroke using [keybd_event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply ..... but i want the next application like word , SAP , IE to appear in Front of all other windows consecutively on the click of a button .... i think is there any API to control the other applications to bring to foreground and focus on it

Comment: You mean other than the SetForegroundWindow api I mentioned?

Comment: And where would that button be if you put another application in front of it? Maybe you should reconsider your design or describe in more detail what you wish to achieve.

Comment: yes of course .... actually there would be a  Non - Modal dialog boxes which is Coded in excel VBA will float around that every active application like (Search Dialog box in Office ) .. and that will have the buttons on it  to go the next application .... that excel form will be on Non Modal mode to every application that is on foreground .. that excel will contain all the code and will be the centralized controlled of all applications

Comment: And why was this written in Excel VBA again?

Comment: @Prabu - VBA non-modal means non-modal with respect to Excel only, not to any other application.

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks for your kind suggestions.. could you please say me that developing applications in visual studio C# express editions is free cost or should we pay for its license for enterprise uses ...i hope in visual studio i can have the non - modal dialog boxes

Comment: @Prabu - I have used the Express version but I'm not familiar with the specific differences between that and the Enterprise version(s).  I suspect though that in terms of your specific "non-modal" requirement there would be no difference.

Comment: The enterprise versions have some more advanced features for managing projects, and having multiple mixed-language projects in a project group/solution. Single projects can be programmed in the express edition perfectly. You will have much more possibilities than in VBA.